# starting PyQt4 timer in separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, animation, pyqt4, qthread

I have method that animates two fullscreen windows up/down, since the animation was little jaggy, I have decided to run the animation as a separate thread, I am not sure if this is a solution to jagged animation, however I want to give it a try. now when I tried to call the method that does the animation
like this

```
try:
    t = Thread(None, self.animateUpSlideShow, None)
    t.start()
    t.join()
except Exception as errtxt:
    print errtxt
```

I got following error

```
QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread
```

Here is the method below:

```
def animateUpSlideShow(self):
    """ animate the slideshow window back up to view mode
        and starts the slideShowBase where it was paused.
    """
    if self._slideShowWin:
        self.animateUpGallery()
        self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self._slideShowWin, "geometry")
        self._slideShowWin.bar.show()
        self._slideShowWin.bar.galrBtn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/galryIcon.png'))
        self.animation.setDuration(self.__animRate)
        self.animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QRect(0, self.__sh,
         self.__sw, self.__sh))
        self.animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, self.__sw, self.__sh))
        self.animation.start()
        self._slideShowWin.activateWindow()
        self._slideShowWin.raise_()
        self._slideShowWin.playPause()
```

so how should I animate the windows in a separate thread without getting the above error ?

**Update**
I used QThreads like this following the example on internet but jagged animation is still there when gallery animate slides upwards [see link for full code](https://github.com/sanfx/slideShow/blob/develop/python/gallery.py):

```
def _animateUpOpen(self):
    """ this method calls the method that animate the windows,
        helps in separating toggle button call from keyboard
        key press calls
    """
    self.workThread = WorkThread()
    self.connect( self.workThread, QtCore.SIGNAL("update(QString)"), self.animateUpSlideShow)
    self.workThread.start()
    # self.animateUpSlideShow()

class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(1):
            time.sleep(0.3) # artificial time delay
            self.emit( QtCore.SIGNAL('update(QString)'), "from work thread " + str(i) )
            self.terminate()
        return
```

please help implementing correctly :-)

Comment: As the error suggests, use [QThread](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qthread.html).

Comment: `thread.start` immediately followed by `thread.join` almost never makes sense. It's basically the same as just executing the threads target method synchronously.

Comment: @dilbert : I have tried using `QThread` but still the fullscreen window if image gallery animates up in a jagged animation, not smoothly...
Could you please look at the code and see if I have implemented correctly.

Comment: I think the Qt library has its own means of timing. I think you need to use a `QTimer`. Also, the time delay could be too high, try 0.05.